# how to make one to many mapping in hibernate struts2

Tags: sql, hibernate, struts2, one-to-one, nativequery

i am having a tables

```
login [login_id, login name]

user[username, login_id, domain_id]

doamin[domain_id,domain_name]
```

i will pass a login name. and i need to get the  domain name the sql query for that is

```
SELECT m_domain.email  FROM    (   ots_web.m_user m_user
       JOIN
          ots_web.m_domain m_domain
       ON (m_user.domain_fk = m_domain.domain_pk_id))
   JOIN
      ots_web.m_login m_login
   ON (m_user.login_fk = m_login.login_pk_id)  WHERE (m_login.uname = 'jai')
```

ho to do this in hibernate with struts2

Comment: Honestly I see nothing related to hibernate nor struts in this question

Answer (score 0):

```
select d.domain_name
from login l
  inner join user u on u.login_id = l.login_id
  inner join domain d on d.domain_id = u.domain_id
where l.login_name = 'value'
```

Comment: i want this in hibernate mapping